# Case insensitive schema object names with case sensitive comparisons

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, collation, case-sensitive

Is there any way to mix case **insensitive** schema object names with case **sensitive** comparisons in SQL Server?

All string columns in my database use a CS (case sensitive) collation however I can't switch to a CS collation at the database level because it's managed by a legacy application that uses inconsistent schema object name casing in the queries it makes.

For example, I need the following query to successfully execute and return 0:

```
select count(*) from PeRsOn where 'A' = 'a'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can additionally specify the collation for the literals, which is then used instead of the ones specified on the instance, database or column level:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM PeRsOn 
WHERE 'A' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Unfortunately the legacy application is DB agnostic so I can't use this MSSQL specific syntax. In fact, the example query I gave is the generic approach used to determine whether the underlying DB is case sensitive or not.

Comment: @NathanBaulch - You need to either change the DB collation to be case sensitive or add an explicit `COLLATE` clause to your queries to make them case sensitive. There is no other way of getting a case sensitive comparison.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping to find a way to independently configure schema object name and comparison sensitivity at the database level.